# Representar los datos de moneda en un edittext

Tags: android-studio, json

Ya obtuve la parte gráfica de los formatos gracias a un json. Pero ahora mi pregunta es ¿como hago para representar esos datos en un edittext formateado?. No he hallado la forma de obtener los datos de del archivo json para a si mismo formatear el edittext con un DecimalFormat o NumberFormat no se.  Ayuda por favor gracias.

```
     private void ObtenerDatosJson(){
        String url = "https://....";
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray myJsonArray = response.getJSONArray("results");
                for (int i = 0; i<myJsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject myJsonObje = myJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String currencyName = myJsonObje.getString("currencyName");
                    String currencyId = myJsonObje.getString("currencyId");
                }


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    queue.add(request);
}
```

//Estructura del Json

"results": [
    {
      "currencyId": "GQE",
      "currencyName": "Central African CFA franc",
      "name": "Equatorial Guinea",
      "alpha3": "GNQ",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "GQ"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "XAF",
      "currencyName": "Central African CFA franc",
      "name": "Chad",
      "alpha3": "TCD",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "TD"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "XOF",
      "currencyName": "West African CFA franc",
      "name": "Benin",
      "alpha3": "BEN",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "BJ"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "BDT",
      "currencyName": "Bangladeshi taka",
      "name": "Bangladesh",
      "alpha3": "BGD",
      "currencySymbol": "৳",
      "id": "BD"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "XAF",
      "currencyName": "Central African CFA franc",
      "name": "Congo",
      "alpha3": "COG",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "CG"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "GEL",
      "currencyName": "Georgian lari",
      "name": "Georgia",
      "alpha3": "GEO",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "GE"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "HTG",
      "currencyName": "Haitian gourde",
      "name": "Haiti",
      "alpha3": "HTI",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "HT"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "KWD",
      "currencyName": "Kuwaiti dinar",
      "name": "Kuwait",
      "alpha3": "KWT",
      "currencySymbol": "د.ك",
      "id": "KW"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "LSL",
      "currencyName": "Lesotho loti",
      "name": "Lesotho",
      "alpha3": "LSO",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "LS"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "MMK",
      "currencyName": "Myanma kyat",
      "name": "Myanmar",
      "alpha3": "MMR",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "MM"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "XPF",
      "currencyName": "CFP franc",
      "name": "New Caledonia",
      "alpha3": "NCL",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "NC"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "WST",
      "currencyName": "Samoan tala",
      "name": "Samoa (Western)",
      "alpha3": "WSM",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "WS"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "TND",
      "currencyName": "Tunisian dinar",
      "name": "Tunisia",
      "alpha3": "TUN",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "TN"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "RWF",
      "currencyName": "Rwandan franc",
      "name": "Rwanda",
      "alpha3": "RWA",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "RW"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "PGK",
      "currencyName": "Papua New Guinean kina",
      "name": "Papua New Guinea",
      "alpha3": "PNG",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "PG"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "DZD",
      "currencyName": "Algerian dinar",
      "name": "Algeria",
      "alpha3": "DZA",
      "currencySymbol": "DA",
      "id": "DZ"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "XPF",
      "currencyName": "CFP franc",
      "name": "French Polynesia",
      "alpha3": "PYF",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "PF"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "GHS",
      "currencyName": "Ghanaian cedi",
      "name": "Ghana",
      "alpha3": "GHA",
      "currencySymbol": "GH₵",
      "id": "GH"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "GNF",
      "currencyName": "Guinean franc",
      "name": "Guinea",
      "alpha3": "GIN",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "GN"
    },
    {
      "currencyId": "LYD",
      "currencyName": "Libyan dinar",
      "name": "Libya",
      "alpha3": "LBY",
      "currencySymbol": "$",
      "id": "LY"
    },

Comment: No podrias tener todos los formatos al mismo tiempo porque unos no son compatibles con otros. tu editText solo puede respetar un formato a la vez.

Comment: Erick Silva. lo que voy a hacer es programar una variable que arroje los diferentes tipos de formatos de monedas de acuerdoa ala elección del usuario

Comment: Algo asi...    switch (codigoDivisa){
            case "Argentina":
                codigoDivisa = "0.00";
                break;
            case "Chile":
                codigoDivisa = "#,###,###,###";
                break;
            case "Colombia":
                codigoDivisa = "#,###,###,###";
                break;
            case "Brasil":
                codigoDivisa = "0.00";
                break;
                default:
                    break;
        }

Comment: ¿Y cuál es la estructura del json?

Comment: Fernando ya deje la estructura del json